# Facebook Graph API: Webhook for LIKE and UNLIKE plus receiving the user

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, webhooks

I have subscribed to the "feed" event with a webhook. So far I receive the following object when someone clicks on the "like" button of my page:

```
{"entry": [
    {"changes": [
        {
            "field":"feed",
            "value":{
                "item":"like",
                "verb":"add",
                "user_id":11111111111111
            }
        }],
    "id":"2222222222222",
    "time":33333333
    }],
"object":"page"}
```

Question 1: I wounder, is it possible to also get an event when the user "unlikes" the page?

Question 2: With this user_id, how can I get the user object from facebook? Is this the "real" facebook user id (i could not get an user object through the graph explorer so far) or is a page specific id of the user?

Thanks in advance!

---

EDIT: For Question 2, I just needed to add the page access_token to the request to get the user object.

Comment: You’re talking about an actual like of the page itself here - not a like on one of the page’s posts? I am surprised that this sends a _feed_ update in the first place, because the likes of a page have little to do with the feed. // Did you check the user id using your own app id in Graph API Explorer? (If it is an app-scoped id, then it of course won’t work with other apps.)